# How to configure MySQL to rollback when using TransactionScope?

Tags: c#, mysql, transactionscope

I've spent a week trying to get transactions working for my MySQL database. Still no success. Running `Windows 7 x64`, `MySQL Server 5.6.7-rc` and `MySQL .NET Connector 6.6.4`.

MySQL claims that `TransactionScope` is supported (I've read the entire Internet by now), so I'm guessing I need some kind of special configuration to get it working. Here's what I've tried so far:

**autocommit=0**

- In `my.ini` I've added `autocommit=0` below the `[mysqld]` section.
- In `my.ini` I've added `init_connect='SET autocommit=0'` below the `[mysqld]` section.
- In Service Manager, I've added `--autocommit=0` as a command line parameter.
- I've verified that `SELECT @@autocommit` returns 0.

**sql_mode=TRADITIONAL**

- In `my.ini` I've added `sql-mode="TRADITIONAL"` below the `[mysqld]` section.
- In Service Manager, I've added `--sql-mode=TRADITIONAL` as a command line parameter.

**Distributed Transaction Coordinator**

- I've tried enabling/disabling the DTC service.

The sample below throws an exception (`System.Transactions.TransactionException` exceptions must be enabled via Ctr+Alt+E) immediately when calling `Open()`. The error message is **The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction.**. Obviously, the server is not happy with the transaction stuff - which is proven by the fact that a rollback does NOT occur.

```
var factory = System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("MySql.Data.MySqlClient");

using (var transaction = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope())
{
    var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
    connection.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=test;User ID=user;Password=user";
    connection.Open(); // <-- silent TransactionException here!

    var command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE TestTable (ID INT) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;";

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TestTable (ID) VALUES (123);";
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // ATTENTION! This should imply a rollback!
    // transaction.Complete();
}
```

The sample code works for `SQL Server` so I know for sure that this problem has something to do with `MySQL`.

**QUESTION:** I've tried everything. What do I need to do to get this `TransactionScope` code working for `MySQL`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL will automatically commit the active transaction on executing a DDL statement (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cannot-roll-back.html). So anything after the CREATE TABLE will not be part of the transaction.

The same thing would happen if you performed the SQL statements as follows:

```
START TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE TestTable (ID INT) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO TestTable (ID) VALUES (123);
ROLLBACK;
```

Try changing your code to:

```
var factory = MySqlClientFactory.Instance;
string connectionString = "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=test;User ID=user;Password=user";

// DDL cannot be performed in transaction as will commit
using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
{
    connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    connection.Open();

    var command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE TestTable (ID INT) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;";
    command.ExecuteNonQuery(); // will always commit here
}

// DML can be performed in transaction
using (var transaction = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope())
using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
{
    connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    connection.Open();   

    var command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TestTable (ID) VALUES (123);";
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // should rollback here
    //transaction.Complete();
}
```

Comment: What you're saying is correct. However, the latest version of the `MySQL .NET Connector` does not support transaction scopes in the same (superb) manner that `SQL Server` does. More specifically, creating nested connections (which makes sense for a connect-do-stuff-disconnect application) yields problems.

Comment: I'm not sure where a nested connection would be required above. If you wrap each SQL command in an connect-execute-disconnect (as above) then you would never nest, right?

Comment: If you have several APIs with transactions, you end up with nested connections: `GetDocumentsUsingTransaction() { ... GetTextUsingTransaction() ... }`.